# Why does foreground job ignore job control signals when Bash is running as PID 1?

Tags: bash, init, job-control

When `bash` is invoked as **pid 1** directly through the kernel option `init=/bin/bash --login`, it will issue something like this before prompting:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

And **no keyboard-generated signals (e.g ^Z, ^C, ^) work**.

To solve this problem, I wrote a simple program `init1.c` (like a simplified `sulogin`) as following:

```c
/* init1.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *options[] = {"--login", NULL};
  int tty_fd = -1;

  printf("\n----- Bash Init 1 -----\n\n");

  /* Make bash as session leader. */
  if (setsid() == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "setsid()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  /* Make /dev/tty1 as controlling terminal of Bash. */
  tty_fd = open("/dev/tty1", O_RDWR);
  if (tty_fd == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "open()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  /* Re-connect stdin, stdout, stderr to the new tty. */
  dup2(tty_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
  dup2(tty_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(tty_fd, STDERR_FILENO);
  close(tty_fd);
  
  execv("/bin/bash", options);
}
```

Compiled it as `init1`, then invoked it as **pid 1** (i.e Bash running as **pid 1**), the preceding error messages disappear and some signals (e.g Ctrl-C, Ctrl-\) work, but job control signals (e.g Ctrl-Z) still not (unexpected).

So to make job control signals work, I revised the code above as `init2.c` (just `fork()`):

```c
/* init2.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *options[] = {"--login", NULL};
  pid_t pid = -1;
  int tty_fd = -1;
  
  printf("\n----- Bash Init 2 -----\n\n");
  
  pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "fork()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
  /* Parent. */
  if (pid > 0)
   {
     /* Wait for its child, otherwise all processes would be killed ! */
     while (wait(NULL) > 0)
       ;
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
      
  /* Child. */
  if (setsid() == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "setsid()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }        
  
  /* Make /dev/tty1 as controlling terminal of Bash. */
  tty_fd = open("/dev/tty1", O_RDWR);
  if (tty_fd == -1)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d : %s\n", "open()", __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  /* Re-connect stdin, stdout, stderr to the new tty. */
  dup2(tty_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
  dup2(tty_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(tty_fd, STDERR_FILENO);
  close(tty_fd);
  
  execv("/bin/bash", options);
}
```

Compiled it as `init2` and invoked as **pid 1** (i.e. finally Bash running as arbitrary PID other than 1), and this time, the job control signals work!

But I didn't figure out why the job control signals work in `init2` (Bash isn't **pid 1**) but not `init1` (Bash is **pid 1**), why does foreground job ignore job control signals when Bash is running as PID 1? It seems that there is something special with **pid 1**.

### Update:

I found a very simple shell [mysh](https://github.com/hungys/mysh) in github which also implements job control, only 949 lines! When I ran it with init1 and init2, this shell also has the same problem! (Thanks to it, I don't have to read the complicated bash source code for figuring out my question. Orz) And the problem lies in waitpid() which doesn't return immediately when SIGTSTP(^Z) reaches. So this issue is not only relative to bash, but also the shells that implement job control. However, I don't understand why does't waitpid() return if SIGTSTP reaches when shell is running as PID 1.

Comment: This looks like a follow-up to [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/691018/108618). Nothing wrong; I'm just noticing, building context, linking related questions together.